# Why 'build' a package instead of using 'extra-deps' in 'stack.yml'?

Tags: haskell-stack

It's my understanding (1) that the `build-depends` section in my project's `.cabal` file will ensure packages specified there are present in the resolver specified in `stack.yml` are available (in the appropriate versions) and used when I test or run my package (e.g., with `stack ghci` or `stack test`, etc.).

I also gather (2) that the `extra-deps` section of my `stack.yml` is used to acquire packages that are not in the specified resolver.

But I'm confused about the role of

```
stack build some-package
```

How does this differ from `extra-deps`? Will `some-package` be used when I `stack test` or `stack ghci` etc.? Why use it instead of just adding `some-package` to `extra-deps`? (And, have I got (1) and (2) right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main purpose of the `build` command is to actually trigger the build, i.e. compilation. By default `stack build` will build all the "local" packages listed in the `stack.yaml`'s `packages` section. If you pass a package name as an argument to `build`, that has usually one of the following two purposes:

1. You want to build only a certain (local) package in a multi-package project
2. Or you you want to install an executable from a non-local package, for example `hlint`. Typically you will do this with `stack install PKG` which is a shortcut for `stack build --copy-bins PKG`.

One core design principle of stack is that builds should be reproducible, i.e. a project with the same code and same configuration should always give the same result for `stack build`.

That means that `stack build` or `stack install` will never change the project configuration or add dependencies to the project.

For more details on the `build` command, take a look at [the relevant docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/).

Comment: So if I `stack build PKG`, PKG has no effect on what `stack build` (using the project's `.cabal` and `stack.yml`) or `stack ghci` or `stack test` see?

Comment: Cool. That seems magical though: I don't see how to outputs (installed packages, e.g.) from `stack build PKG` and `stack build` are segregated? Does doing one just obliterate the other?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: If the `.cabal` for my project simply has `'.'` for `packages` and I run `stack build` in the project directory, I've built a Haskell environment with some specified packages in it so that `stack test` etc. will use only those packages. If I subsequently run `stack build PKG` for some other package not already part of that environment, isn't `PKG` now part of the environment that `stack test` etc. sees?

Comment: You mean that the `stack.yaml` contains only the package in the current directory, right? As I said in my answer, `stack build PKG` will not add any dependencies. For example, if my project configuration is missing e.g. `lens` and I run `stack build lens`, the next run of `stack build` will still fail because the dependency is missing. `stack build` does not change the configuration. The situation is slightly different when you're missing some kind of executable, e.g. a tool like `hlint` or so. In that case `stack build hlint` will put the executabable on an internal path and …

Comment: … any stack command that requires `hlint` will be able to find it.

Comment: That explains a source of my confusion: I'd done `cabal build ghc-mod` and found that the `ghc-mod` stuck around (e.g., `stack exec -- which ghc-mod` finds it in `~/.stack/snapshots/...`).

Comment: To avoid confusing anyone else who may read this: You probably ran `stack build ghc-mod`, right? `cabal` probably wouldn't put an executable into `~/.stack`.